# On Google AppSheet, why the result of LOOKUP isn't what it supposed to be?

Tags: lookup, google-appsheet

For example, I have this simple table on sheet "Login Account":

| User ID | Email |
| --- | --- |
| A001 | john.doe@gmail.com |
| B001 | test@example.com |

And then on AppSheet, I'm using Data --> User Settings to set up a simple login form. I can set up a field (column) named `EMAIL ADDRESS`. The second field (column) is `YOUR ID`, which I give Auto Compute behavior:

```
=LOOKUP([EMAIL ADDRESS],"Login Account","Email","User ID")
```

I also have third field (column) with name `EMAIL MIRROR`, with formula simply copying the content of the `EMAIL ADDRESS`:

```
=(EMAIL)
```

The result:

| EMAIL ADDRESS | YOUR ID | EMAIL MIRROR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (empty, initial) | A001 | (empty) |
| abc@def.com | A001 | abc@def.com |
| john.doe@gmail.com | A001 | john.doe@gmail.com |
| test@example.com | A001 | test@example.com |

The `YOUR ID` column always gives results `A001`, no matter what email I put on `EMAIL ADDRESS` (as long as the email exists). But the `EMAIL MIRROR` always updates successfully to the current `EMAIL ADDRESS`. Why is it like this? How can I use `LOOKUP()` correctly to look up a value using other column value *and* update the display to reflect that result?

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VL-w6Uny86I) tutorial, but making necessary changes to fit my table & scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it helped me to use:

```
[_THISROW].[matchvalue]
```

instead of just `[matchvalue]`

In your example:

```
=LOOKUP([_THISROW].[EMAIL ADDRESS],"Login Account","Email","User ID")
```

More about the solution here:
https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AppSheet-Q-A/Lookup-match-value/m-p/256959

Answer (score 0):

[_THISROW] ahead of the value being matched will solve the issue.

I also think that you should set it to be read only, so users don't mistakenly override the values.